# Trying to use show/hide to slowly fade In/ fade Out a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make to show/hide a paragraph when buttons are pressed. 
But also to look like slow movement up and down.

That's how the HTML look like for example :

```
<button class="hideA">Hide</button>
<button class="showA">show</button>
<p id>Helloooooooooooooooooooooo.</p>
```

And that's how the Jquery code looks like:

```
$(".hideA").click(function(){
    $(".hideA p").hide(function(){
    });
});
$(".showA").click(function(){
    $(".hideA p").show(function(){
    });
});
```

But this code is not running for some reason. please let me know the reason if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove the $(".hideA p")  and use $("p") otherwise you are hiding the Button!

Also, you can specify the paragraph by adding an id to it:

```
<p id="paragraph">Helloooooooooooooooooooooo.</p>
```

Then Try the following code to run it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hideA").click(function(){
        $("#paragraph").hide("slow");
    });
    $(".showA").click(function(){
        $("#paragraph").show("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: there is no need og function(){} call back function , you need to remove it ,  $("#paragraph").show("slow", function(){  }); can be   $("#paragraph").show("slow");

Comment: Yes, no need for it. I had it on the testing alert!  $("#paragraph").show("slow");   will work for sure! @Pranay

Answer (score 1):

for both the below way to work you need to set id of `p` element

```
<button class="hideA">Hide</button>
<button class="showA">show</button>
<p id="para">Helloooooooooooooooooooooo.</p>
```

---

you can try out this way also , by making use of animate function, this will give fill of hiding and lastly it get hidden by visiblity property.

```
   $(".hideA").click(function(){
    $( "#para" )
      .css({opacity: 1, visibility: "hidden"})
      .animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
    });


    $(".showA").click(function(){
     $( "#para" )
     .css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"})
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000); 
    });
```

---

make use of `slideUp` and `slideDown` method . this method provide animation of hiding and showing element but your element stays in DOM

```
$(".hideA").click(function(){
    $("#para").slideUp(function(){
    });
});
$(".showA").click(function(){
    $("#para").slideDown(function(){
    });
});
```

working demo at : https://jsfiddle.net/pranayamr/xttk3r6o/

Comment: you can't use  $(".hideA p")  to target the paragraph

Comment: @DirWolf - got it updated answer ...i focused on question text only...to hide element with animation ...

Comment: @Fabian - set id of p , try now i udpated that also

Comment: Yes that one works now! But I've already used the code above and it does the job. great effort all! much a appreciated.